# How can I select a class element in repeated containers using CSS selector but last?

Tags: html, css, selector

I have this structure:

```
<div id="myMainID">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="pseudoBlock">
                 //Something1                 
          </div>
       </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="pseudoBlock">
                 //Something2                
          </div>
       </div>


       <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="pseudoBlock">
                 //Something3                 
          </div>
       </div>

   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I need to select all `.pseudoBlock` but last to apply style.

I tried with `#myMainID .pseudoBlock:not(:last-of-type)` but it doesn't work and I've found nothing searching by Google.

How can I solve this selector?

Comment: Your sibling hierarchy is at the `.container` level. You therefore need `#myMainID .container:not(:last-of-type) .pseudoBlock` to style all `.pseudoBlock` within a `.container` that isn't the last of its type.

Answer (score 0):

After posting first time I pasted wrong code...but, the answer provided by @chriskirknielsen in comments is correct and I applied it to the correct code:

`#myMainID .col-12:not(:last-child) .pseudoBlock`